# I just found an awesome bug!

Tags: bug, hyperlinks, newsletter

When previewing [a newsletter](https://stackexchange.com/newsletters), the links at the very bottom point to something epic:

[image]

I get that it's a placeholder link, but the "visiting your subscriptions page" and "unsubscribe from all stackexchange.com emails" links can probably be set straight.

That is, of course, unless this is what is actually being emailed out — that'd take it to a whole new level of epic!

Comment: @michaelb958 Jeff said on that question that "the links can't work in the preview". As I mentioned, some of them can. Good find though!